# steps to work with Concurrent program in Oracle apps

Tags: concurrency, plsql

If I create the PL/SQL procedure in oracle SQl Developer, then how to access that PL/SQL procedure in Oracle Application. Also I need the steps to work with the concurrent program in oracle application so that when I run the executable file in the oracle Application, I should get the output in the oracle SQL developer for the executed procedure in the Oracle Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE sample AS

procedure demo(errbuf out NOCOPY varchar2,
               retcode out NOCOPY varchar2);

END sample;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY sample AS

procedure demo(errbuf out NOCOPY varchar2,
               retcode out NOCOPY varchar2)
is
begin
   --
   -- If you want to write some output call:
   --
   FND_FILE.put_line(FND_FILE.output,'Starting processing:');
   --
   -- NOTE:
   --    to write to log use FND_FILE.log instead of FND_FILE.output
   --

--

FND_FILE.put_line(FND_FILE.output,'Done!');

commit;

-- Return 0 for successful completion.
   errbuf := '';
   retcode := '0';

exception
   when others then
      errbuf := sqlerrm;
      retcode := '2';
end demo;

END sample;

Login-to Oracle applications

## 1. Define Executable

NAVIGATE:
Concurrent ->
   Program ->
      Executable:

Executable: sample_demo
   Short name: asample_demo
  Application: Application Object Library ---change to your requirement
  Description: Demonstration of APPS pl/sql concurrent program
   Exe Method: PL/SQL Procedure
Exe File Name: sample.demo

## 2. Define Program

NAVIGATE:
Concurrent ->
  Program ->
     Define:

```
Program: Demonstration of APPS pl/sql concurrent program
```

Short Name: PACKAGE_PROCEDURE
Application: Application Object Library

Executable: asample_demo

## 3. Add Program to the SYSADMIN Responsibility REPORT Group

NAVIGATE:
Security ->
   Responsibility ->
      Requests

Query for "System Administrator Reports" Group  --using F11 and Ctrl+F11

In the Requests detail-form add the following row:

Type: Program
   Name: Demonstration of APPS pl/sql concurrent program

You can now run this pl/sql package.procedure through APPS Concurrent Manager.

## 4. Run Program from Standard Request Submission

Go to SRS(Standard Request Submission) submit your program

:-)

Comment: I get `ORA-24344: success with compilation error` when trying to compile package body. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you navigate to that " Standard Request Submission"part?

Comment: Hi ahmedov type show err(If you using sql*plus), first compile before execution (right click --> execution --> compile), then you can able to find the errors .